# PHP Laravel class returning a couple of classes with static properties - C# static class in static class

Tags: php, laravel, static

In C# I can create static class that have inside a couple of static classes that I can use as namespaces for constants, for example:

```
public static class ConstantTypes{

   public static class ErrorTypes{
      public static string Log = "Log";
   }
}
```

Than in app I can use:

```
ConstantTypes.ErrorTypes.Log
```

How to do the same in `PHP` in `Laravel`?

Now I created two classes:

```
 class LogTypeConstants
    {
        const MYCONST = 'val';
    }

use App\Common\LogTypeConstants;

class AppConstants
{
    
    static function LogTypes() {
        
        $logTypeConstants = new LogTypeConstants();
        return $logTypeConstants;
    }
}
```

And in `Laravel` controller I can use:

```
 $logType = AppConstants::LogTypes()::MYCONST;
```

Is better way to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bold statement, never create static functions unless absolute necessary, a nightmare with dependency injection. With that out of the way, what i feel is the consensus on this, is just to use the constants and access them on the class.

```
class LogTypeConstants
{
    public const MYCONST = 'val';
}

LogTypeConstants::MYCONST; // would access it
```

An perfect example is how `Symfony` implements their `HTTP` status codes on the [Response](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/6058b19318aa27773cfb3014e9b11be54ac30aa2/Response.php#L29) class. In `Laravel` you would access it like so.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

public function store() {
    ...
    return $this->response($object, Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```

Comment: Ok, is any posibility to make like that `\AppConstants::LogType::StatusError` ? Because I can group properties in groups otherwise all properties will be mixed

Comment: I dont think so in PHP, seperate classes for each constant is needed